# Object at URL has og:type of 'website'. The property 'recipe' requires an object of og:type

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, facebook-graph-api

I've implemented FB timeline integration,i've posted successfully on timeline using below code:

```
FB.api('/me/_recpbox:cook', 'post', { recipe: 'http://samples.ogp.me/187362391384273' }, function (response) {
if (!response || response.error) {
alert(response.error.message);
} else {
alert('Post ID: ' + response.id);
}
});
```

here the URL comes from fb app settings,(The Open Graph Dashboard page has a 'Get Code' link next to your action)

I have to give my own path and Image,currently the image appearing is the one i've set for my app,can any1tell how can i give my own URL and Image. i have tried givinga my website path but it says:

```
Object at URL has og:type of 'website'. The property 'recipe' requires an object of og:type
```

Answer (score 0):

The URL that you supply for the recipe object must have the appropriate og tags in the head. See http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/tutorial/ for more information.

Specifically pay attention to the 'Create an object page' section in Step 4 : Publish Actions.

Another point to note is that the URL you supply must be accessible by Facebook, or else you will get the same error.

Comment: I've implemented from same article,but when i am giving my webste(or localhost) path, it is not accepting and in case of localhost i am unable to check it in debugger tool of FB

Comment: localhost will not work as the URL must be accessible by Facebook

Comment: Localhost can work if the app is setup with localhost as its canvas, no?

Answer (score 0):

If you get the error "Object at URL has og:type of 'x'. The property requires an object of og:type 'y', then you probably have the wrong combination of [ogen graph metatags](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-objects/). The page for the url in `og:url` must have the right `og:type`